# Iterate over dictionary to get specific key's count

Tags: python

I am just a beginner in coding, trying to self teach python, then I got a lot of questions in my mind. so consider I have a `main.py` with a function `def catch_urls(**kwargs):`  I will pass key:value arguments while running the file. My requirement here is there will be a bunch of arguments I pass to the function of which I need to find out the count of pattern matching keys- that means

```
main.py type=internal url1=google.com url2=yahoo.com timeout=10s url3=stackoverflow.com
```

Q1. How to get the count of how many `url1, url2, url3, ....` is given in arguments ? these url* count will vary on each runs then how to get the count of this pattern keys ?  can we do something like psuedo code like `count(url*)`

Q2. Using `**kwargs` can I actually get these arguments passed into execution ? or do I need to use some library called "click" or so to get these arguments passed into my function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments arrive as strings in `sys.argv`.  So, given your example, `sys.argv` would be a list containing:

```
[
    "main.py",
    "type=internal",
    "url1=google.com",
    "url2=yahoo.com",
    "timeout=10s",
    "url3=stackoverflow,.com"
]
```

You can parse those yourself, or you can use the `argparse` module to parse them.

It's not usually productive to spent a lot of time optimizing code that only gets used once.  You could certainly say:

```
    cnt = sum(i.startswith("url") for i in sys.argv)
```

`**kwargs` is used for functions within a program.  It's not involved in command line arguments.

Comment: Excellent quick win code you provided. I might take a while to code like these. Thanks for that. I am planning to create a Cloudfunction, where gcp cloud scheduler to send msg with all these dict arguments  via pub-sub to invoke this cloudfunction. So this cloudfunction will catch these and process it. This is my idea I am trying to materialize.

Comment: Well, cloud components don't communicate via command line.  You're usually processing JSON over HTML, or something like that, where the rules are very different.  You'll find out when you dig in deeper.